# How to run a method right after method dispatch and before the method is called?

Tags: ruby

When I have the following:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "#{__method__} was called and found within #{self}"
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    puts "#{meth} was called and was not found within #{self}"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar 
# => bar was called and found within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
foo.baz 
# => baz was called and was not found within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
```

I assume that when the method is found, the method dispatch looks a bit like so:

```
foo.bar was asked to be called
Search methods defined within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
Method `bar` found
Call the `bar` method
```

And for methods not found:

```
foo.baz was asked to be called
Search methods defined within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
Method `baz` not found 
Search methods defined within the parent of #<Foo:0x100138a98>
Method `baz` not found
And so on until it hits the parent that has no parent
Loop back around and see if #<Foo:0x100138a98> has a `method_missing` method defined
Method `method_missing` found
Call the `method_missing` method
```

I would like to step in like so:

```
foo.bar was asked to be called
Search methods defined within #<Foo:0x100138a98> to see it has a `method_dispatched` method
Method `method_dispatched` found
Calling `method_dispatched`
Search methods defined within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
...
```

This would allow developers to do something like below:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "#{__method__} was called and found within #{self}"
  end

  def method_missing(meth, *args, &blk)
    puts "#{meth} was called and was not found within #{self}"
  end

  def method_dispatched(meth, *args, &blk)
    puts "#{meth} was called within #{self}..."
    puts "continuing with the method dispatch..."
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar 
# => bar was called within #<Foo:0x100138a98>...
# => continuing with the method dispatch...
# => bar was called and found within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
foo.baz 
# => bar was called within #<Foo:0x100138a98>...
# => continuing with the method dispatch...
# => baz was called and was not found within #<Foo:0x100138a98>
```

This brings me to the question..

Is this possible?

Comment: There's more to finding a method than just a class and its parents. You might find this article useful if you haven't already: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/030-issue-1-method-lookup.html

Comment: @c00lryguy: Are you downvoting me because I answered the question you originally asked?

Comment: Well it just wasn't relevant to the question. I only changed the title. It was like you read the title, skipped the body and answered it.

Comment: @c00lryguy: I'll delete the answer if you get rid of the downvote.

Comment: "You last voted on this answer
1 hour ago
Your vote is now locked in
unless this answer is edited" So edit it, then I'll un-downvote, then delete. =p

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a callback for what you're looking for.   I would read up on Ruby Delegators for a possible solution that's more elegant than what I've sketched below.

You can wrap the object and intercept on method_missing.

```
class A
  def foo
    puts "hi there, I'm A"
  end 
end 

maybe have B inherit A? 
class B 
  def initialize 
    @a = A.new
  end 

  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "hi there, I'm in B"
    @a.send(m, *args, &block) if @a.respond_to? m
    puts "all done"
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a Ruby beginner here, but I have some working solution. So please comment on the code if you think something is not ruby-esque.

The idea is to alias the methods that you have and undef_method the original method. This will create a alias for all your instance methods. You can then have a method_missing that can call method_dispatched and then the actual method.

```
class Test
        def foo
                "foo"
        end

        def method_dispatched(meth, *args, &blk)
                puts "#{meth} was called within #{self}..."
                puts "continuing with the method dispatch..."
        end

        def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
                method_dispatched(name, args, block)  #Calls your standard dispatcher

                if (respond_to?('_' + name.to_s)) # Check if we have a aliased method
                        send('_' + name.to_s)
                else
                        "undef"    #Let the caller know that we cant handle this.
                end
        end

        instance_methods(false).each do |meth|
                if meth != 'method_missing' and meth != 'method_dispatched'
                        alias_method "_#{meth}", meth
                        remove_method(meth)
                end
        end

end

t = Test.new
puts t.foo()
puts t.undefined_method()
```

Comment: Just curious. Did you get a chance to try this out?